# Can I say that $f(x)=0$ converges to zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

we have a sequence $a_1$, with all terms larger than or equal to $0$. which has finitely many terms before the sequence becomes all $0$s.

Now suppose I had a function = $min${of the values of $a_1$ from n=1 to $\infty$}.

It is clear that this function will give $0$. However,would this $0$ be a constant or the sequence of all $0$s? Im 99% sure it will be a constant, but just not certain.

But more importantly, could I say that this function $f(x)=0$ converges to $0$? I feel like it should, since I can give, for any epsilon, any x would have $0$ distance from $0$ which must be less than all $\epsilon$>$0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be just zero. In fact what you're defining is not really a 'function', rather is it just a constant that is equal to zero, and since it doesn't have any parameter that can vary it doesn't 'converge'.

You could however define a function as $$f(T)=\min\{a_t\mid t=1,...,T\}$$ and then $f(T)$ converges to zero as $T\to\infty$.

Comment: So you're saying $f(x)=0$ doesn't converge to 0? But for any epsilon you give me, I'll give you a trivial value d and k, for which $|x-k|<d => |f(k)-0|<\epsilon$. Note how $f(k)=0$.

Comment: @MrMachine I don't understand why you say your definition above describes a function. What's its parameter?

Comment: $f(x)= max$ {x} is a function isn't it?

Comment: I'm suspecting we are actually talking about the same thing and the $f(T)$ function I've defined is what you've had in mind all along. In that sense, yes, it converges. But if you're simply talking about the number $x=\min\{a_t\mid t\in\mathbb{N}\}$, then saying this constant "converges" simply isn't a well defined concept.

Comment: @MrMachine Oh, so in that case you are talking about a function that takes the sequence as an argument? In that case convergence would be a much more complicated concept, since you'd say that if you take a convergent sequence of sequences, say ${a_t}^n\to b_t$ (along with some appropriate norm for sequences), then the minimum (or maximum) value $f(a_t)$ converges as $n\to\infty$. Is this really what you want to say? I had the feeling you have one fixed sequence in mind and were thinking about taking the minimum over more and more of its terms...

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to say, but I see you're telling me that its some constant that the expression gives, if the function goes from n=1 to infinity.